# Is there any way to carry out voltammetry without a potentiostat?

Tags: electrochemistry

I'm trying to do a voltammetry experiment, but my high school doesn't want to have to buy a potentiostat (understandably, I know they are very expensive). Is there any way to carry out a voltammetry experiment, either linear sweep or cyclic, without a potentiostat? Or am I doomed to have to go back to the drawing board...

I should mention that the physics lab has some equipment like variable power sources, but not much--my school kind of under-appreciates science--and I was planning on creating a cruddy makeshift three-electrode cell.

Comment: Are you good with op-amps?   Do you have access platinum, or some other type of highly inert electrodes?

Comment: No I don't really have access to those things, but thanks.

Comment: For good science projects keep it simple. A very prominent scientist once told me if an experiment cannot be explained in a simple manner, then it is not worth doing. I have seen this same scientist turn down countless requests for equipment, so making do with what you have is part of scientific research. Three electrode experiments do form the basis of many chemical sensing and corrosion resistance technologies, but these experiments are tough to get to work, especially on the budget of a high school lab. Best of luck on the project.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I've already moved back to brainstorming. I'm not an experienced user here so I don't know how to close a question, but if a moderator could/should(?) do that, then double thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a valid question. This project is entirely possible, but I would not advise it for a high school research project based on my experience building these. Much better projects are available.

A nonreactive electrode, for example gold or platinum, is required for good results.

Knowledge of op-amp design, or some other feedback control system, which is taught in advanced electronics courses is needed.  The control system fixes the potential between the the reference and the working electrode by drawing current from the third electrode.  The current drawn is measured to give some information about the system.

The Wikipedia article shows the circuit need, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiostat.

The open source cheapstat is available: http://web.chem.ucsb.edu/~kwp/cheapstat/

Integrated versions of the circuit are available. http://www.ti.com/product/LMP91000.  Evaluation kit ~$100 http://www.ti.com/tool/LMP91000EVM.

Information on making electrodes: https://publiclab.org/notes/JSummers/01-09-2014/potentiostat-notes-5-how-to-make-low-cost-electrodes

It is possible to build a potentiostat without advanced knowledge of electronics; however, this runs into costs. Getting experiments done with the equipment, resources, and funding available is something every scientists faces.

Comment: Maybe you can raise $100 for CheapStat, http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0023783
It does not solve the electrode problem, but at least you can try something

Comment: Edited answer based on comment from ssavec.

Comment: @ssavec, I can't find the article I saw a while ago, but I remember seeing a way of making a reference electrode with a sieve stuck to the bottom of a glass tube + a silver wire (silver is not too expensive). Counter electrode could be graphite, and working electrode could also be graphite.

Comment: @Sean_Doris Is this the article?  https://publiclab.org/notes/JSummers/01-09-2014/potentiostat-notes-5-how-to-make-low-cost-electrodes

Comment: @Agriculturist, that's the one!